# set_column is not applying color format to columns of large excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to highlight columns using different font colour for easy user notification but it is not happening.  tried all sorts but not sure what the problem is. I tried commenting other sheets apart from several other tries

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("C:\myDocs\Python\MAY_CCPS_CCSO_Preload_Validated.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
     CCSO_Preload_Sheet1.to_excel(writer, index = False, sheet_name='SO_1Header')
#     CCSO_Preload_Sheet2.to_excel(writer, index = False, sheet_name="SO_2Item",engine='xlsxwriter')
#     CCSO_Preload_Sheet3.to_excel(writer, index = False, sheet_name="SO_3_Schedules",engine='xlsxwriter')
#     CCSO_Preload_Sheet4.to_excel(writer, index = False, sheet_name="SO_4Partners",engine='xlsxwriter')
#     CCSO_Preload_Sheet5.to_excel(writer, index = False, sheet_name="SO_5Long_Text",engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['SO_1Header']
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'red', 'bg_color': 'yellow'})
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 40, format1)
writer.save()
```

Comment: After pasting code into a question (or answer), immediately select what you just pasted and either type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the editor interface. That will deal with formatting the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that you are using a `with` context manager but the formatting code is outside that block. So the file is already closed when you are trying to format it.

Changing the indentation the program works as expected:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

CCSO_Preload_Sheet1 = pd.DataFrame({'Heading1': data,
                                    'Heading2': data})

with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    CCSO_Preload_Sheet1.to_excel(writer, 
                                  index = False, 
                                  sheet_name='SO_1Header')

    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['SO_1Header']

    format1 = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 
                                   'font_color': 'red', 
                                   'bg_color': 'yellow'})

    worksheet.set_column('B:B', 40, format1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes I ultimately figured that out during trial and error and it worked. Thanks for your response.